# Allowing a process in screen to restart itself

Tags: linux, script, python, gnu-screen

System is Debian Whezy x64.
I currently use screen to start programs as user rather than root. It looks like this:
In /etc/rc.local, I call

```
su -c "/home/user/scripts/startup" user
```

Then, in /home/user/scripts/startup, I call a few python programs like this:

```
screen -dmS my_program python /home/user/my_program.py
```

They all start fine. The problem is that these programs tend to update themselves every week or so. When the program updates, it tries to restart itself. Upon the program's restart, the screen session terminates, and the program does not start again. So, after a few days, I notice the program isn't working and need to start it again by hand.

Is there something I can do to ensure that the program will start itself again after a program restart?

Edit: I've read something about screen's "zombie mode" that allows it to stay active, but I don't know how to invoke it at boot.

Thanks

Comment: Within screen and within a shell script: ‛while : ; do  myprogram ; done‛

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a script that runs in infinite loop and watches that program is running.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -q <program> || <start_program>; sleep 5; done
```

Start the script in screen.

Comment: I used the same idea, but was not as fancy. Just used Ott's While Do Done example. Thanks!